# Getting first sibling of second instance using Xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to extract information from [this page](https://www.bandsintown.com/e/103275458-nayo-jones-at-promise-of-justice-initiative?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event):

I'm trying to extract the time (6:30 PM).

My strategy is to find the second instance of the date (Mar. 31st, 2022), and then get the first sibling of that. Photo here (I want the part boxed in yellow):

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
#Get First Date (Date at top of the page)
    try:
        first_date = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/a/"] + div + div')
        first_date = first_date[0].text
    except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        print ("first_date doesn't exist")
        continue


 #Get time.  This will the first sibling of the second instance of date
    try:
        event_time = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[text()='" + first_date + "'][1]/following-sibling::div")
        print(event_time[0].text)
    except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        continue
```

However, this is not getting me what I want.  What am I doing wrong here?  I'm looking for a way to get the first sibling of the second instance using Xpath.

Comment: maybe first run without `try/except` to see what makes problem. maybe it explain problem. You could also get some parent element and check what is in its HTML. It helps to see if it is good direction.

Comment: maybe you should search element which has text with `PM` - `//div[contains(@text, " PM") or contains(@text, " AM")]`

Comment: That won't really work because there will be other divs with descriptive text that contains the phrases AM or PM.  I'm looking for feedback on why my syntax is not working (using sibling after indexing of xpath).

Comment: But if it is first element with PM then you can use `find_element` to get first . And if it is always second,etc. then you can get all and later use `[1]` in Python

Comment: I can get it with `'//div[contains(text(), "PM")]'` - it has to be `text()` instead of `@text`

Comment: when I display all `event_time` from your code then I see time as last element, not first, `event_time[-1].text`

Comment: it needs `( )` to get elements before execute `[1]`, and it needs `[2]` because xpath start counting at `1`, not `0`

Comment: it seems this page has [API](https://artists.bandsintown.com/support/events-widget) and maybe you could get information without scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is first element with `PM` / `AM` so I would use `find_element` with

```
'//div[contains(text(), " PM") or contains(text(), " AM")]'
```

like this

```
item = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(), " PM") or contains(text(), " AM")]')
print(item.text)
```

I use space before `PM`/`AM` to make sure it is not inside word.

---

Your xpath works when I add `( )` so it first gets divs and later select by index.
Without `()` it may treats `[text()="..."][1]` like `[text()="..." and 1]`.
And it needs `[2]` instead of `[1]` because xpath start counting at `1`, not `0`

```
"(//div[text()='" + first_date + "'])[2]/following-sibling::div"
```

---

Full working example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import time

url = 'https://www.bandsintown.com/e/103275458-nayo-jones-at-promise-of-justice-initiative?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event'

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

item = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(), " PM") or contains(text(), " AM")]')
print(item.text)
print('---')

first_date = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/a/"] + div + div')
first_date = first_date[0].text
        
event_time = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(//div[text()='" + first_date + "'])[2]/following-sibling::div")
print(event_time[0].text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following xpath will give you date and time.

**date**:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Promise of Justice Initiative']/following::div[4]").text)
```

**time**:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Promise of Justice Initiative']/following::div[5]").text)
```

or your use.

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("
//a[contains(@href,'https://www.bandsintown.com/v/')]/following::div[contains(text(), 'PM') or contains(text(), 'AM')]").text)
```